# excel vba open files and copy documents based on monotonically increasing name

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an excel sheet that will handle copying data from a series of daily logs that are stored in the file name format: yyyy dd Mmmm.xls (i.e. "2015 01 November.xls").

I allow the user to provide a start and end date as cell values and read them into VBA (easily done)

```
SDate = Range("B1").Value
EDate = Range("B2").Value
```

I can create a list in another column of the dates using a Do Until loop:

```
Range("G1").Select
NextDate = SDate
Do Until NextDate > EDate
   ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
   ActiveCEll.Offset(1,0).Select
   NextDate = NextDate + 1
Loop
```

The issue I'm having is building a file name so that inside of the loop I can open the file with the given name (As: yyyy dd Mmmm*.* , as I recently transitioned that sheet from an xls file to an xlsm file and they periodically have initials at the end of the file name). Using:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "X:DirectoryInfo\2015 12 December\" & NextDate & "*.*"
```

within my Do loop gives me an error as excel attempts to open a file named "11/1/2015*.*" which doesn't exist. How can I change the name for the file to the correct format? I also need to change the directory as necessary in front of the file to match the file name format (Thankfully the directories are always formatted the same as the file name but with the month displayed twice in the form "yyyy mm Mmmm")

Comment: Maybe `...cember\" & format(NextDate , "yyyy dd mmmm\*\.\*")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use code like:

```
Sub BenA()
   Dim SDate As Date, EDate As Date
   Dim NextDate As Date, rng As Range

   SDate = Range("B1").Value
   EDate = Range("B2").Value
   Set rng = Range("G1")
   NextDate = SDate

   Do Until NextDate > EDate
      rng.Value = "C:\TestFolder\" & Format(NextDate, "yyyy dd mmmm") & ".xls"
      Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
      NextDate = NextDate + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Our file open table will be like:

[image]

This will make the `Workbooks.Open` statement easier.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much.